# How to configure jdtls for nvim?

Tags: java, neovim

I'm trying to configure [jdtls](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#jdtls) on a Lua based nvim environment following the [video](https://youtu.be/6F3ONwrCxMg) of the following [series](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhoH5vyxr6Qq41NFL4GvhFp-WLd5xzIzZ).

I could install the `jdtls` LSP server and it seems to work fine. When opening a Java file, it shows me the errors in the source code if any.

So I was trying to change a setting, say this one:

```
java.codeGeneration.generateComments
```

from `false` to `true` but it never showed `true` as a value.

I created the `jdtls.lua` file under the settings directory, containing:

```
return {                                                                                                                                              
   settings = {                                                                                                                            
     java = {                                                                                                                              
       codeGeneration = {                                                                                                                  
         generateComments = true                                                                                                           
       },                                                                                                                                             
       classPath = {
       },                                                                                                                                  
       home = "",                                                                                                                          
     },                                                                                                                                    
   },                                                                                                                                          
 }
```

And I added in the `lsp-installer.lua` file:

```
if server.name == "jdtls" then
   local jdtls_opts = require("user.lsp.settings.jdtls")
   opts = vim.tbl_deep_extend("force", jdtls_opts, opts)
end
```

Here are my files:

```
16:08 $ tree
.
├── init.lua
├── lua
│   └── user
│       ├── cmp.lua
│       ├── colorschemes.lua
│       ├── keymaps.lua
│       ├── lsp
│       │   ├── handlers.lua
│       │   ├── init.lua
│       │   ├── lsp-installer.lua
│       │   └── settings
│       │       ├── jdtls.lua
│       │       ├── jsonls.lua
│       │       └── sumneko_lua.lua
│       ├── options.lua
│       └── plugins.lua
├── plugin
│   └── packer_compiled.lua
├── README.md
└── typescript.lua
```